# remove rows based on column value in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following data, I want to remove rows where the country value is ['US','EU','pl','nl','es']

```
#standardSQL
with table as (
  select 'DE' country, 520 number union all
  select 'NL' country, 520 number union all
  select 'US' country, 530 number union all
  select 'AT' country, 560 number union all
  select 'NL' country, 720 number union all
  select 'CH' country, 5280 number union all
  select 'FR' country, 5250 number union all
  select 'BE' country, 5280 number union all
  select 'IT' country, 4890 number union all
  select 'EU' country, 5005 number union all
  select 'pl' country, 5007 number union all
  select 'nl' country, 5005 number union all
  select 'es' country, 5070 number union all
  select 'ROE' country, 5700 number
)
select * from table
where country not in ['US','EU','pl','nl','es']
```

I understand that where statement doesn't work like that but this is something I wanted to achieve, can some help here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Change the [] for () after the not in, and you will get it right. So: where country not in ('US','EU','pl','nl','es')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below instead

```
select * from table
where not lower(country) in ('us','eu','pl','nl','es')
```